# How to compare two cells in the same character array [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, compare, character

I need to compare two cells in a character array.

I was wondering if

array[i][j]==array[i+1][j+1]

would actually compare the character values inside of the array.

Comment: please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) if it solved your question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its `char[][]` - yes, if it is `Char[][]` - (capital C) then no, as the latter one is a pointer and thus the address is compared